# How to find offending format error in Vim tags file

Tags: vim, tags

I've recently seen this error whenever I hit autocomplete macros in Vim (e.g. ctrl-n):

`E431: Format error in tags file "tags"`

The tags file is generated with Exuberant Ctags and it's about 1MB. How do I find the error that's triggering this error?

Comment: In my case, just below the `E431` error message, there was another message that specified where in the tags file the error occurred, e.g. `Before byte 63964633`. So resolving the issue was a matter of opening the tags file with Vim and entering `:go 63964633` to go to the byte after which the error occurred. This happened to be a line that was 1404 bytes long. Removing this line resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really long function names can cause this error. You can find these functions by opening the tags file in vim and looking for method names longer than 50 chars.

```
/^[^\t]{50,}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would still like to know if there's a way to handle them. Also, I'm guessing your value of 50 is arbitrary. All quite strange.

Answer (score 14):

I found some extra lines present before !_TAG_FILE_FORMAT line in the generated tags file.When i remove these extra lines, vim starts working.

Comment: This indeed works oddly enough, now the questions is how those lines end up there. It wouldn't be much of a work flow if we'd have to remove those every time we create a new tag file. Did you have any luck in finding out the cause?

Answer (score 6):

I think ctags has a problem with parsing java script files. Excluding it from tagging fixed this problem for me.

```
ctags -R --exclude=*.js .
```

Answer (score 4):

The *tags database* is line-oriented; after the header (line(s) starting with `!_TAG_FILE_...`), each line corresponds to a tag.

By using *binary search*, you should be able to quickly locate the offending line(s): Save a copy of the tags file, remove one half, test. If you still get the error, repeat (until you're down to one line). Else, take the other half and repeat.

This is a general troubleshooting technique; for example, it's also helpful to locate problems in Vim plugins (by disabling one half of them).

Comment: I found it with that. For others reading, tags is read every time, so just doing a ctrl-p or ctrl-n after saving the file will do it. I ended up going to top of tags file, deleting half the file, and trying in Vim. I found the error was due to a generated Rails assets file during development and if I'd visually inspected the tags file I would have spotted it as it was a very long term (255+ characters).

Comment: A tags-lint tool would still be nice but seems to not be any.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by generating tags only for git files.

```
git ls-files | ctags --links=no --languages=javascript,java,python -L-
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [jaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070199/jastr)'s answer:

I found this, which states that lines longer that 512 characters break vim:

`1. Keep the text short, because:
   - The line length that Vi can handle is limited to 512 characters.`

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/FORMAT

EDIT: updated source: https://neovim.io/doc/user/vi_diff.html

`Maximum length of a line in a tags file: 512 bytes.`

I indeed did have a tag line longer that 512 characters - removing that line fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Your reference refers to a version of Vi from 1998, not modern ViM

Comment: You're right! I've added a reference to neovim, which is the flavor of vim I use most frequently, and is a more up-to-date source.

Comment: The same still applies in regular Vim too (https://vimhelp.org/vi_diff.txt.html shows same for Vim 8.1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by rebuilding the tags.

First remove all tags files and then rebuild tags from your project.

I think the reason was i built the tags files twice, first time the tags built for child directories, then build the parent directories.

So, the child directories tags couldn't contain some parent directories information.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, seems not all file formats are well supported. I used the option -L to create tags for only c and c++ files ,the issue went away .
You might want to try the following , just substitute the *.postfix with the corresponding format you need.

```
ctags -L $(find . -name *.c -or -name *.cpp -or -name *.h -or -name *.lua )
```

Comment: this gives error 
ctags -L $(find . -name *.c -or -name *.cpp -or -name *.h -or -name *.lua )
-bash: /usr/bin/ctags: Argument list too long

Answer (score -1):

Removing extra lines non-comforming to the ctags standard fix the issue for me.

Comment: Isn't that circular logic, ie leads to effectively the same question of how do I know which lines are non-confirming?